# How to determine the current rating of Litz wire winding at high frequency?

Tags: inductor, high-frequency, maximum-ratings

How can we determine the current rating of a litz wire winding at high frequency?

**This is my try:**
For example, if we use 660/38 litz at 85kHz, we can see the equivalent AWG is 10 ([reference](http://edge.rit.edu/edge/P10022/public/team_docs/Wires_Casing/NEWENGLANDlitzSpecs.pdf)). Then, according to [this table](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm), the amperage for the equivalent AWG of 10 is 15A.

But is it same for high-frequency current?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an easy question to answer, as there are many things going on in wire at high frequencies.

While skin effect causes the current to travel nearer to the surface of the strands, the size of the stranding will have been chosen to make that effect tolerable.  There is also the proximity effect - the field from a conductor affects nearby conductors and increases their impedance. On a regular spiral lay stranded wire with insulated strands, this would have the effect of greatly reducing the current in the inner strands of the bundle, hence the need for Litz wire, which has the stranding arranged such that each strand spends a more or less equal proportion of its length in the interior and exterior of the bundle, thus evening out the currents carried by each strand. The specific lay pattern of the wire therefore has an effect on the current distribution.
  The thermal dissipation of the wire is also not easy to determine, since the strands are insulated, the dissipation from the inside of the bundle by radial conduction from contact with other strands is limited, and the heat has to mostly follow the length of the strand to its next turn at the outside layer where it can be cooled by convection/conduction.

There's good write-up [here](https://www.elektrisola.com/hf-litz-wire-litz/products/terminology-basics/technical-basics-and-calculation.html)

Answer (score 1):

At high frequency, conductors having large cross-sectional area become less effective to carry current due to [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect). So to minimize this effect and increase efficiency, multiple small conductors are used together (Litz wire).

To estimate the current capacity of a given Litz wire, you need to know the effective cross-sectional area of each strand and the number of strands. Multiply them to find total effective area, convert it to AWG and use the AWG table to determine the current capacity. ( I'll let you do the research here)

Or you can use this table (source: wiretron.com)  if you want a quick answer.

```
 Frequency vs. AWG Strand Size

 All Values in KHz

1    To 10.0  – 30 AWG
10   To 50.0  – 33 AWG
50   To 100.0 – 36 AWG
100  To 200.0 – 38 AWG
200  To 400.0 – 40 AWG
400  To 800.0 – 42 AWG
800  To 1600  – 44 AWG
1600 To 3200  – 46 AWG
3200 To 5000  – 48 AWG
```